# Proof check on the fact that the closure of a set is the union of the set with its boundary.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The definition of boundary for a set $A \in X$ ($X$ is a metric space) I am given is $$\operatorname{Bnd}(A) = \{ x \in X \mid \forall r \ B(x,r) \cap A^c \ne \emptyset, B(x,r) \cap A \ne \emptyset \} $$

The definition of the closure I have to work with is that the closure $\bar{A}$ of a set $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$.

I want to prove that $\bar{A} = A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$. ( I have checked for some similar questions and result but they all use different definitions from mine.)

I proceed by taking $x \in \bar{A}$ then $x \in \bigcap_{ \alpha \in a} F_{\alpha}$ where the $F_{\alpha}$ are all closed sets that contain A. Because they all contain $A$ then  $x \in A$ and this implies that $x \in A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ so $\bar{A} \subset  A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$.

Now I take $x \in A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ if $x \in A$ I am done so I assume $x \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$. I want to show that $y \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)^c$ iff $y \in (\bigcap_{ \alpha \in a} F_{\alpha})^c = \bigcup_{ \alpha \in a} F_{\alpha}^c$.

Saying $ \operatorname{Bnd}d(A)^c$ is saying $\{ y \in X  \exists r \mid B(x,r) \cap A^c = \emptyset$ or $B(x,r) \cap A = \emptyset \}$.

But here I am unsure how to proceed and I think I am making things difficult.

Edit: $F_{\alpha}$ are closed by definition.

Comment: @Clayton Yes sorry all the closed set.

Comment: In the first part of your proof, you seem to use the fact that $A \cup Bnd(A)$ is closed. But you haven't proved this.

Comment: @Bungo I can't or better the verbal exercise asked to use the definitions I gave :( .  Where did I used that $A \cup Bnd(A)$ is closed? By the way thanks for your answers.

Comment: Aren't you tacitly assuming that $A \cup Bnd(A)$ is one of the $F_{\alpha}$? If not, then how are you concluding that $\overline{A} \subset A \cup Bnd(A)$? I guess I don't understand your argument. You also seem to conclude that $x \in \overline A$ implies $x \in A$, which is false in general.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that if $x \in \bar{A}$ then $x$ is in one of the $F_{\alpha}$ and that this means that $x \in A$ but I now see that this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof:

**Step 1:** We prove that $\overline A \subseteq A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$.

Clearly $A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ is a set containing $A$. If $A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ is closed, then it is one of the $F_{\alpha}$ (the closed sets containing $A$), and therefore $\overline A = \bigcap F_{\alpha} \subseteq A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$.

So for this step, all we have to do is show that $A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ is closed. To do that, we show that its complement is open.

So, suppose that $x \in (A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A))^c = A^c \cap (\operatorname{Bnd}(A))^c$. We need to show that $x$ has a neighborhood $B(x,r)$ contained in $(A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A))^c$.

Assume this is not true for some $x$. Then for every $r$, the neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$. This means that one the following two possibilities must hold: (**1A**) for every $r$, the neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $A$, or (**1B**) for every $r$, the neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $\operatorname{Bnd}(A)$. We show that both of these possibilities leads to a contradiction.

**Possibility 1A:** Every neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $A$. Since $x \in B(x,r)$ and $x \in A^c$, every neighborhood $B(x,r)$ also intersects $A^c$. This means that $x \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$, which is a contradiction.

**Possibility 1B:** Every neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $\operatorname{Bnd}(A)$. Consider what this means for a given $r$. Since $B(x,r)$ intersects $\operatorname{Bnd}(A)$, there is a point $y \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ contained in $B(x,r)$. Since $B(x,r)$ is open, there is also a neighborhood $B(y,r')$ contained in $B(x,r)$. Since $y \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$, the neighborhood $B(y,r')$ contains points in $A$ and in $A^c$. Since $B(y,r') \subseteq B(x,r)$, this means that $B(x,r)$ contains points in $A$ and in $A^c$. Since this is true for any $r$, we conclude that $x \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$, a contradiction.

**Step 2:** We prove that $A \cup \operatorname{Bnd}(A) \subseteq \overline A$.

Clearly $A \subseteq \overline A$, so it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Bnd}(A) \subseteq \overline A = \bigcap F_{\alpha}$.

To do this, we show that $\operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ is contained in every $F_{\alpha}$, i.e., in every closed set that contains $A$.

Suppose this were not true. Then $\operatorname{Bnd}(A) \not\subseteq F_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. So $\operatorname{Bnd}(A) \cap F_{\alpha}^c \neq \emptyset$. This means that some point $x \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$ is contained in the open set $F_{\alpha}^c$. So some neighborhood $B(x,r)$ must also be contained in $F_{\alpha}^c$. But $F_{\alpha}$ contains $A$, so $B(x,r)$ does not intersect $A$. This is a contradiction since $x \in \operatorname{Bnd}(A)$.

**Edited** to give the full proof instead of hints, to address comments by the OP.

Comment: Thank you a lot Bungo, I went and took a look at a proof that a set is closed iff it contains all its limit points. Since the course I am following has not defined limit points yet, and this exercises is for the weekend and we have no more lessons before the weekend, I was wondering if there exists a proof without using limit points? What do you think?

Comment: @Monolite: Sure, I'll modify the sketch appropriately. I assume you are using the definition that a set is closed if and only if its complement is open?

Comment: For Step 1 I think the first contradiction is that because $x \in (A \cup Bnd(A))^c =$ then $x$ is in both $A^c$ and $Bnd(A)^c$ so because $x \in A^c$ then $B(x,r) \cap A^c \ne \emptyset$ but if for every $r$ the neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $A$ this means $x \in Bnd(A)$ but $x$ is already in $Bnd(A)^c$ so we get a contradiction.

Comment: For Step 2 I think that the contradiction is that because $x \in Bnd(A)$ then $B(x,r) \cap A$ must be different from the empty set $\forall r$, but we have shown that there is a $B(x,r)$ contained in a set disjoint from $A$. Contradiction.

Comment: For Step 1 part 2 I am having some difficulties.

Comment: @Monolite: I updated my answer to a full proof to address your questions.